# Uniqueness in $y'=P (t) y+Q (t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My book says that an ODE of the type
 $$ \tag{#} y'=P (t) y+Q (t)$$ 
where $P,Q$ are continuous functions on some  interval $I$ has the general solution $$\tag{$*$} y (t)=e^{\int P (t) dt}\left\lbrace c+\int Q (t) e^{-\int P (t) dt }dt \right\rbrace$$
This book proves that a function of the type $(*)$  is solution of $(\#)$ but not the other verse of the claim. Is there a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is another solution (let's call it z). Since the differential equation is linear, what do we know about the difference y-z? Or (to be precisely) what can we derive for the difference?